# Mysql command cannot connect to remote host

Tags: mysql, kali-linux

I have a problem with mysql command on Kali Linux OS.
I'm using this command to connect to MySQL database on remote computer in local network (IP address: 172.16.64.81) but when i tried this command, it always force me to connect localhost and output the error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

[image: Screenshot of error]

Clearly, i don't want to connect localhost and this is my command i used here:

```
mysql -u root -p -P 13306 -h 172.16.64.81
```

Please note that this is credential i'm using to login remote database. Username is 'root' and password is empty. I don't know why 'mysql' command enforces me to connect back to localhost? I don't use mysql database on my localhost.
Flag:

- `-u | --user` -- username
- `-p | --password` -- password
- `-h | --host` -- Remote IP or Hostname
- `-P | --port` -- optional Port number

Comment: you need to define a user with the grant to connect. currently your user has a grant only for localhost.

Comment: yes. the username & password you are trying is probably for local mysql server. for remote server, you can find root pass from at the time of creation of db

Comment: Yes, thank all. Please note that this is credential i'm using to login remote database. Username is 'root' and password is empty. I don't know why 'mysql' command enforces me to connect back to localhost?

Answer (score 0):

is the port you are using to connect correct? usually its 3306 for MySQL.
I was facing a similar error until I tried this way and it works:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 172.16.40.23
```